# Why no output from Kendo-UI template?

Tags: templates, kendo-ui

I am trying to use Kendo-UI templates to display values from a JavaScript array, but nothing is appearing in the HTML.

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <table>
        # for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { #
            <tr><td>#: tableData[i]#</td></tr>    
        # } #
     </table>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());
    var tableData = ["1", "2"];
    template(tableData);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found three problems: 1) the template(tableData) must be set to a DOM element, as in $("#output").html(template(tableData)); and 2) that the variable name inside the template must be data; and 3) the code that loads the template must be executed after the DOM is ready. Here is the complete and corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());
            var tableData = ["1", "2"];
            $("#output").html(template(tableData));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <table>
            # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
                <tr><td>#=data[i]#</td</tr>  
            # } #
            </table>
       </script>            
    </form>
</body>
```